# RadioGroup to if statement?

Tags: android

so theres 8 radiogroups and it has 2 buttons each (Id's are Yes and No) what i want is if there are 4 YES then **openPositiveDialog** else **OpenNegativeDialog**

Here are the codes

````
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int RadioGroupIdFever = RadioGroupFever.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        radioButton1 = (RadioButton)findViewById(RadioGroupIdFever);

        int RadioGroupIdDryCough = RadioGroupDryCough.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        radioButton2 = (RadioButton)findViewById(RadioGroupIdDryCough);

        int RadioGroupIdRunnyNose = RadioGroupRunnyNose.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        radioButton3 = (RadioButton)findViewById(RadioGroupIdRunnyNose);

        int RadioGroupIdSoreThroat = RadioGroupSoreThroat.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        radioButton4 = (RadioButton)findViewById(RadioGroupIdSoreThroat);

        int RadioGroupIdAchesAndPain = RadioGroupAchesAndPain.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        radioButton5 = (RadioButton)findViewById(RadioGroupIdAchesAndPain);

        int RadioGroupIdFatigue = RadioGroupFatigue.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        radioButton6 = (RadioButton)findViewById(RadioGroupIdFatigue);

        int RadioGroupIdBreathing = RadioGroupBreathing.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        radioButton7 = (RadioButton)findViewById(RadioGroupIdBreathing);

        int RadioGroupIdMentalState = RadioGroupMentalState.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        radioButton8 = (RadioButton)findViewById(RadioGroupIdMentalState);

        if(v==Button_Next)
            SubmitToSheet();


            openPositiveDialog();

            openNegativeDialog();```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did after so many trial and errors

````
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int RadioGroupIdFever = RadioGroupFever.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        radioButton1 = (RadioButton)findViewById(RadioGroupIdFever);

        int RadioGroupIdDryCough = RadioGroupDryCough.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        radioButton2 = (RadioButton)findViewById(RadioGroupIdDryCough);

        int RadioGroupIdRunnyNose = RadioGroupRunnyNose.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        radioButton3 = (RadioButton)findViewById(RadioGroupIdRunnyNose);

        int RadioGroupIdSoreThroat = RadioGroupSoreThroat.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        radioButton4 = (RadioButton)findViewById(RadioGroupIdSoreThroat);

        int RadioGroupIdAchesAndPain = RadioGroupAchesAndPain.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        radioButton5 = (RadioButton)findViewById(RadioGroupIdAchesAndPain);

        int RadioGroupIdFatigue = RadioGroupFatigue.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        radioButton6 = (RadioButton)findViewById(RadioGroupIdFatigue);

        int RadioGroupIdBreathing = RadioGroupBreathing.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        radioButton7 = (RadioButton)findViewById(RadioGroupIdBreathing);

        int RadioGroupIdMentalState = RadioGroupMentalState.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        radioButton8 = (RadioButton)findViewById(RadioGroupIdMentalState);


        int noOfYes = 0;

        if(radioButton.isChecked()){
            noOfYes++;
        }
        if(radioButton18.isChecked()){
            noOfYes++;
        }
        if(radioButton20.isChecked()){
            noOfYes++;
        }
        if(radioButton22.isChecked()){
            noOfYes++;
        }
        if(radioButton24.isChecked()){
            noOfYes++;
        }
        if(radioButton26.isChecked()){
            noOfYes++;
        }
        if(radioButton28.isChecked()){
            noOfYes++;
        }
        if(radioButton30.isChecked()){
            noOfYes++;
        }

        if(v==Button_Next) {
            SubmitToSheet();
            if (noOfYes <= 3) {
                openPositiveDialog();
            } else {
                openNegativeDialog();
            }
        }

    }```
````

Answer (score 0):

Try recording the number of `yes` 's and number of `no` 's...then comparing them after the selection is complete..eg

```java
//The variables to hold the records...
private int noOfYes = 0,noOfNo = 0; //create the vars

@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int RadioGroupIdFever = RadioGroupFever.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        radioButton1 = (RadioButton)findViewById(RadioGroupIdFever);
//check if radioButton1 is yes..and increment noOfYes..
        int RadioGroupIdDryCough = RadioGroupDryCough.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        radioButton2 = (RadioButton)findViewById(RadioGroupIdDryCough);
// same here..
        int RadioGroupIdRunnyNose = RadioGroupRunnyNose.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        radioButton3 = (RadioButton)findViewById(RadioGroupIdRunnyNose);
//....
        int RadioGroupIdSoreThroat = RadioGroupSoreThroat.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        radioButton4 = (RadioButton)findViewById(RadioGroupIdSoreThroat);
///....
        int RadioGroupIdAchesAndPain = RadioGroupAchesAndPain.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        radioButton5 = (RadioButton)findViewById(RadioGroupIdAchesAndPain);
//.............
//Now after summing up yes's and no's..compare
if (noOfYes >= 4)
// openPositiveDialog....
 else
// openNegativeDialog.....
```

Hope it solves your problem....

Comment: Do I need to put something below this statement ```private int noOfYes = 0,noOfNo = 0;```

Comment: Not actually...just leave that and increament whenever its a `yes` or `no` accordimgly...

Comment: This can be done by recording either of them. No need to use two variables. We can just record the number of yes and compare with 4.

Comment: yeah....thats right...i thought you needed the `no` s with the statement `SubmitToSheet()` ...but you can do that if its non- required